# Change Link color on div hover

Tags: css, class, hover

I have a div that has a link in it, right now if I hover over the link it chnages color, but I want to hover over the div aswell to chnage the color, here is the code:

```
<div class="first_product margin_right left">
<a href="/link">
</a><div class="first_product_text"><a href="/link"></a><a href="link">Automation&nbsp;<span>+</span></a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm all for using Jquery, but if you want to avoid it

HTML:

```
 <div class="first_product margin_right left">
      <div class="first_product_text">
           <a href="/link"></a>
           <a href="link">Automation&nbsp;<span>+</span></a>
      </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.first_product_text:hover{background-color:#f22;}
```

heres the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJHwH/)
​

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

CSS:

```
.first_product_text div:hover a {color:#HOVERCOLOUR;}
```